# Application Controller helper methods not available for Views Specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, authlogic, rspec2

I have a helper method called `current_user` in my Application Controller (used with Authlogic).

Spec for views using that helper fail (but the view is working when i use the browser)

`ActionView::Template::Error: undefined local variable or method 'current_user' for #<#<Class:0x0000000229b060>:0x00000002004248>`

I use rspec 2.6.0.

Anyone had the same problem? Please advice. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can stub out the method on `view`.

`view.stub(:current_user).and_return(user)`

This will also work in helper specs.

Comment: FYI: The view object is also available in helper specs.

Answer (score 4):

Controller-defined helper methods are not included in the helper object.

http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/dir/helper-specs/helper-spec

Comment: Hello David, Thank you for answering so quickly. If I understand correctly your answer, views that use helpers defined in controllers with helper_method cannot be tested with rspec because rspec cannot access those helpers... Somehow that does not feel right...

Comment: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/119#issuecomment-309978 seems to indicate that this should be fixed, however it appears not to be (as of rspec-rails 2.10.1)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this one: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper_method.

You can define helper inside the ApplicationController, and use it across the controllers AND views.

Answer (score 0):

check right documentation for specs view

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-14/docs/view-specs/view-spec#passing-view-spec-that-stubs-a-helper-method